# GPDB : SSH permission denied (public key)

Tags: greenplum, hawq

When trying to ssh (from greenplum system user) one of datanode from Master gpdb host.

env - gpdb 4.3.10

**Getting error**

[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ ssh datanode

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$

**WE Tried**
Tried on  pivotal docs 
https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/203777546-gpssh-exkeys-Fails-with-Error-Permission-denied-During-Local-Key-Exchange

Also,  observed node not able to SSH any of data node/master host.

```
**Here is verbose mode  -v with SSH info**

debug1: Host 'datanode01' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/gpadmin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gpadmin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gpadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gpadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Comment: I would retry that Pivotal doc.  It correctly steps you through how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sure.  going to give one more try on it. the same link i posted here

Comment: I just tried on it.  still, facing the same error

Comment: @JonRoberts I tried checking  ssh config .  notable thing is one of datanode  and other stand by node able to connect properly except this node.

Comment: I would like to do this manually copy the public key from the source system to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the destination system.  is that Ok?  because  SSH copy pub key not possible  Or can you please advice possible ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem isn't the root login as that doc suggests but rather, password authentication is disabled.  Try running this on ALL nodes:

```
sudo sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service sshd restart
echo "gpadmin:changeme" | sudo chpasswd
```

Then retry gpssh-exkeys as gpadmin.

```
gpssh-exkey -f all_hosts
```

After you exchange the keys, you can disable password authentication again.

```
sudo sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```